# increment value and keep change

Tags: c#

I'm trying to increment my value by 10. Every time the user says `add` then 5 will be added to the current number.  However in my code when I call `add` it always returns 15 and never adds 5 to 5.
every time the user say add the currNum should change for example if currNum is 10 then they say Add it will be 15 if they say add again it should be 20

```
  switch (e.Result.Text.ToUpperInvariant())
  {
     case "ADD":
        lblText.Content = "Adding"; 
        int currNum = 10;
        int plus = 5;
        currNum = currNum + plus; 
        break;
    default;
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to say? Please be more clear.

Comment: [Interpunction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interpunction).

Comment: Um, your code always adds 10 and 5... why do you expect it to get anything other than 15?

Comment: That's some badass indentation you got there.

Comment: every time the user say add the currNum should change for example if currNum is 10 then they say Add it will be 15 if they say add again it should be 20 and so on

Answer (score 4):

You are always ending up with 15 because you set `currNum` to 10 inside the method. If you are trying to increment an overall value, your incrementing value should begin outside of any methods that might affect it. In the code below, the value starts at 10 and is incremented every time the second block of code is called:

```
int currNum = 10;
```

Define the variable currNum outside of a method, e.g. at the beginning of your class. Then, whenever you call the following method, it will be incremented by 5.

```
switch (e.Result.Text.ToUpperInvariant())
{
   case "ADD":
   lblText.Content = "Adding"; 
   int plus = 5;
   currNum = currNum + plus; 
   break;
}
```

Comment: That will add to 15 as well?? I'm confused at what you're doing. How are you incrementing the number of inputs?

Comment: @FrankPytel I think the key is `your incrementing value should begin outside of any methods that might affect it`.  Maybe it would be more clear if the `int currNum = 10;` snippet was in it's own code block?

Comment: @sǝɯɐſ Agreed James. And that shoots my answer out. But it wasn't supposed to be perfect. :-D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have edited for clarity.

Comment: @FrankPytel What you should do is create an attribute called currentNumer. Initialize at 10 when you create your object. Then when you use the switch, adding the value of 5 every time will have the effect that you seek !

Comment: Thank you so much @Xanthippe and Kevin Avignon

Comment: @KevinAvignon Yep. I know how to do it. I just can't do it in 2 seconds like all the down voters here. So I'm not only gonna leave up the downvote answers. I'm gonna try to push it harder. Thanks Kevin. I appreciate your input. Have a Great Day!! Please see edits if you like.

Answer (score -5):

*HEAVILY EDITED TO SHOW I KNOW HOW TO DO IT*

```
    public static void unique()
    {
        Stream uniqueStream = File.Open(dataFolder + UniqueFile, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader readerUnique = new StreamReader(uniqueStream);

        string line = null;

        line = readerUnique.ReadToEnd();

        int countUnique = 0;
        int output = 0;
        //int max = 9999;

        if (linesUnique.Length > countUnique /*&& Convert.ToInt32(linesUnique) < max*/ )
        {
            output = Convert.ToInt32(line);
            countUnique++;
            output = countUnique + output;
        }

        readerUnique.Close();

        StreamWriter writer;

        using (writer = new StreamWriter(dataFolder + UniqueFile))
        {
            writer.Write(output);
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The OP does not want to add 5 k times, he wants to add 5 whenever the user makes an input. So you do not know how often this will apply. Btw.: Please format your answer a bit

Comment: Why did you copy the code from one of your question as an answer to this question? it doesn't help at all... It's not even related!

Comment: I can't even comprehend how this is related to the question at all. How could this be helpful? Maybe if you explained, we could see it? And please keep the unnecessary commentary out of your posts.